# Rails form submission not happening in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails 5.2 app, where I'm using `form_with`, which is generating this HTML:

```
<form id="post-0" class="" action="/posts.js" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

The form is submitting successfully to the PostController's `create` action.

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.account.posts.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Post added.' }
        format.js { render :create, status: :created }
      else
        format.html { render :index }
        format.js { render :create, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

It *is* then rendering the JS view:
**app/views/posts/create.js.erb**

```
alert('created');
```

However, in my browser, I'm literally redirected to `http://localhost:3000/posts.js` where it shows the javascript code. Meaning, the form submit **doesn't** seem to be happening in the background.

I would have expected to still have stayed on the page the form was on, with a Javascript Alert appearing saying "created".

Is there's something silly I've missed? Seems to me it must be something with `form_with` that I'm not doing right.

I tried swapping it for `form_for @post, remote: true, format: :js do ...` but that had the same problem.

At this point, I can't tell if the problem is in View that shows the form, or in the Controller's `create` action. The controller **is** rendering `create.js.erb` and the URL shown is `http://localhost:3000/posts.js` which does seem to suggest it's a Form problem in the View.

This app is Rails 5.2. I'm not sure it's relevant, but I've removed the Asset Pipeline for Webpacker, I **do** have `rails-ujs` installed (as it is showing the confirm dialog in these `link_to` links as expected `<%= link_to('Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }) %>`

Comment: remove this { render :create, status: :created } from format.js and try again. @Turgs

Comment: Same problem. No change @wasipeer

Comment: Now check the browser console for possible errors

Comment: Did you try specifying the `action` name? like this : 
```format.js { render action: 'create', status: :created }```
Normally you don't even need to specify the aciton, it will by default search for `create.js.erb`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Form submissions can occur locally (ie. not remote) due to a number of reasons.

Some common reasons local submission may be occurring when using **[form_with](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)** include:

> **local: true**

The **`local`** attribute is optional for `form_with`. If not provided, `form_with` will by **default** set `local: false`.

- `true` will set the form to be submitted locally (standard form submission), not remote/asynchronously.
- `false` will set the form to be submitted remotely/asynchronously.

Any value other than `false` (including `:false` which is a *symbol* not a *boolean*) will be interpreted as the value being `true` (ie. submit locally).

> **Javascript triggered form submissions**

Despite the setting of the `local` attribute being set to something that should trigger a remote/asynchronous form submission, the form may still be submitting locally if you're triggering the form `submit` event via Javascript.

In the example given in question, the HTML generated by the `form_with` use is as expected, so attributes provided to `form_with` are not the problem in this instance.

If javascript is being used to submit the form, that could be the problem. For example, even with `data-remote="true"` on the form, this javascript will be a problem:

```
document.getElementById('form-0').submit();
```

This submits the form, but [doesn't raise a submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) for `rails-ujs` to intercept via an `onsubmit` event handler.

**Working with the [Rails Unobtrusive Javascript Adapter](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/How-to-trigger-a-form-submit-from-code)**

To have the form submission triggered by javascript (whether you're using jQuery, Stimulus JS, or anything else) you need to use a mechanism that [rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) (or [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)) will intercept for you.

Rails provides the `Rails.fire` custom javascript event wrapper in `rails-ujs`, which can by used like this:

```
Rails.fire(document.getElementById('form-0'), 'submit');
```

Comment: Triggering the form submission via javascript's native `submit()` call was my problem. I'm now using `Rails.fire` and it works great.

Comment: RE the Ruby question you just deleted, from a shell you can determine the current ruby version: `ruby -v #=> ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]`. If you use RVM (see `rvm.io`) for managing Ruby versions and gems you can execute (from a shell) `rvm list known` to obtain a list known Ruby version and can install one (say v2.6.3) with the command `rvm install 2.6.3`. You should be able to use this information to create a [cron job](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/) that runs at intervals you specify. I'll delete this when I figure you've seen it.

Comment: Can I use `Rails.fire(document.getElementById('form-0'), 'submit')` while providing `local: true`?

Comment: Just so it is noted, likely only tangentially related, I was having issues with my Rails app, it absolutely refused to update and save to my psql db that was correctly configured. 

This fix made everything work as desired; the changes were only being saved locally and now the database updates as it should. Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a very basic mistake. By using `ajax` you can't use `format.js`. This `Ruby` Module is used to redirect the page. instead you should be using `render json: { status: 200}`

Comment: Thanks. I use `format.js` all the time as responses. It works, but something funky going on in this instance with how the form itself is submitting.

Answer (score 0):

saw your job on Upwork. No need to spend $100 on this!

```
<%= form_with url: content_export_path, method: :post, id: 'ce_form1', data: { remote: true } %>
```

Look where the remote: true declaration is... (inside data hash)

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks. On the generated HTML for the form element, it was already generating `data-remote="true"`